# Limit GTM Tag to Percentage of Sessions

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a script that I am including on my site via Google Tag Manager.  I'd like to only fire the script for 10% of sessions.  Does anyone know of a way that I can set up a trigger to only fire on a percentage of sessions?

I can implement some logic in the backend to determine if the session falls in the 10% bucket and then pass a dataLayer variable to use in my trigger, but I feel like there should be an easier or more elegant way to handle this type of scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use something like this:

```
<script>
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
if ( rand == 1 ){dataLayer.push('event':'oneOutOfTen')}
</script>
```

And then use a trigger for 'oneOutOfTen'.

If you want to be consistent for a given sessions you should use sessionStorage or a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If you can implement your backend logic in Javascript you can use a custom HTML tag to determine if the session falls in the 10% bucket.

Otherwise through the dataLayer, as you wrote (which for me is the best solution), or through a cookie.